# jQuery FullCalendar - Can I programmatically resize the Calendar

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, autoresize

I'm using FullCalendar, and I realize that if the window is resized, FullCalendar's [default](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs2/display/handleWindowResize) is to handle the window resize and adjust the calendar as needed.

However, I have a slight problem when a **nav sidebar is chosen to slide in/out**, FullCalendar is left with some extra large weekend Saturdays.  (See below).  And the opposite is true when the Nav Sidebar slides back out. (The weekends become quite small).

[image: Big Weekends!]

The only remedy thus far has been to resize window, which then adjusts the calendar.  But I don't want users to have to do this obviously.

Is there a way to programmatically resize/refresh the calendar size **without resizing the window?**

I have tried something like:  `$("#calendar").fullCalendar( 'windowResize' );`  But this doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas on what I could do here?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/display/aspectRatio/?

Comment: This fixed it.  If you make it an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dodinas as requested, the following worked for you for dynamically resizing the calendar.

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/display/aspectRatio/

On initialize:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    aspectRatio: 2
});
```

After initialize:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar('option', 'aspectRatio', 1.8);
```