# resize a primeng schedule (based on fullcalendar)

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, schedule, primeng

I'm building a relatively complicated calendar using PrimeNG's schedule, which is basically just a component wrapper for the jquery FullCalendar, I believe. You can see it [here](https://dev.probono.net/ma/massprobono2/calendar/?view=calendar2).

I'm attempting to switch between a large calendar view and a small one (by clicking the link at the top right of the control). The small one has custom actions, like clicking on a day brings up a list of items for that day on the left. It also can filter events according to topic or city, which appear both in the calendar and in the list.

My problem occurs when I attempt to change the size of the calendar. If I remove one instance of the calendar with a small size and replace it with another of a big size, then my events and shading aren't rerendered. I can't find a hook in p-schedule to indicate when it's finished loading so I can call my shading methods. But when I attempt to use css to merely change the size and position of a single calendar (preferred, and the way it's set up on my site right now) the height of the initial loading of the calendar cannot be adjusted to the needed height at the new size. The height stays the same. I've tried grabbing the component with jquery and setting aspectRatio that way (according to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21519947/jquery-fullcalendar-can-i-programmatically-resize-the-calendar)), but that doesn't seem to work. Am I just missing the way to grab a fullcalendar control embedded in a schedule component and manipulate it with jquery?

aspectRatio is also declared in schedule.d.ts, so I thought it might be a property I could assign a value to with the #fc component object, but that doesn't work.

The way I'm calling Schedule:

```
<p-schedule 
  [events]="filteredItems" 
  #fc 
  [aspectRatio] = 2 <!--works, but only at initialization-->
  [header]="headerConfig" 
  (onDayClick)="handleDayClick($event.date)"
 ></p-schedule>
```

And my component code. I'm loading jquery in the base page, and declaring $ to be of type 'any'. The things I've tried are at the bottom of the page in the "toggle..." function.

```
  toggleFullCalendar() {
    if( this.fullCalendarOnly ) {
      this.fullCalendarOnly = false;
      // this.headerConfig = this.smallHeaderConfig;
      // $(this.fullcalendar).fullCalendar('render');
      // $(this.fullcalendar).fullCalendar('destroy');
    } else {
      this.fullCalendarOnly = true;
      // $('p-schedule').fullCalendar('option', 'aspectRatio', 1.8);
      // this.headerConfig = this.bigHeaderConfig;
      // $(this.fullcalendar).fullCalendar('render');
      // $(this.fullcalendar).fullCalendar('destroy');
    }
    // this.onDeselected( this.getMenuItemWithID( this.dateMenu.masterArray, this.currentView ));
    this.refreshCalendar( this.currentSelectedDay );
  }
}
```